# Copy Texture2D to leave original unchanged

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to I properly copy a Texture2D in Unity, I've tried using `Graphics.CopyTexture(texture, copy);` to have it tell me that the two images are incompatible, how do I work around this and get a perfect copy of the image, Everything I've looked up either relates to how to crop the copied image or when using RenderTextures but I can't find any information about how to create a copy Texture2D that is identical, in size and pixel colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D-ctor.html) of the Texture2D class, and the methods [SetPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) and [Apply](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html).

```
Texture2D copyTexture = new Texture2D(originalTexture.width, originalTexture.height);
copyTexture.SetPixels(originalTexture.GetPixels());
copyTexture.Apply();
```

You may encounter an error:

```
UnityException: Texture 'YourTexture' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.
```

And as it says. You solve it by clicking your texture in the project tab to open the Import Settings in the Inspector and check the `Read/Write Enabled` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
texture = (Texture2D)SpecMat.GetTexture(name);
                    Texture2D  textureClone = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height, texture.format, false);
                    textureClone.LoadRawTextureData(texture.GetRawTextureData());
                    textureClone.Apply();
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76259027/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).